# Which is most efficient and failproof way to fetch a table which has almost 50 million records using python?

Tags: python, mysql, etl, data-warehouse

I have a requirement where I need to fetch a huge table that is presently stored in MySQL database using python.
I have tried with Limit and offset, but that keeps on getting slowed down with the number of iterations. 
I am using `mysqlclient` for making connections. 
My current requirement is to write it into a file after each iteration.
For testing, I am using CSV but I will switch to `parquet` file format once I find a good solution

```
select * from table_name  limit {} ,{}
```

Please suggest me some of the methods that you are using and it works flawlessly.

code snippet that i am using :

```
i = 1
limit = 1000000
curs.execute("select * from table_name limit 1")
col = [col_[0] for col_ in curs.description]
print(col)

while True:
    start_ = time.time()
    query = f'select * from table_name    limit {i} ,{limit} '
    print(query)
    curs.execute(query)
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    if not len(rows):
        print("done")
        break
    print("###########")
    print(i)
    print("###########")
    end_ = time.time()
    print(f"Runtime of the program is {end_ - start_}")

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=col)
    df_temp.to_csv(f"test_{i}.csv", header=True, index=False)
    # df_total.append(df_temp)
    i = i + limit
```

Or should I consider using different languages like scala?

Comment: Fetch them and do what? Where exactly is the bottleneck? What connector are you using?

Comment: @deceze , so i am fetching and writing it to csv right now (but might switch to parquet in the future) . I am using mysqlclient for making connections

Comment: Pandas seems to be overkill here. Just use Python’s `csv` module, select all rows without limit, and `for..in` over the results row by row and write them to CSV? Perhaps tweak the cursor’s batch reading to keep that process as quick as possible.

Comment: @deceze , i can't fetch all records at once as it may cause a memory issue. Pandas is just for saving the file . That takes mostly 2-3 seconds in each iteration. But right now I am just concerned about fetching the records efficiently and in more faster way

Comment: The problem is that you’re using `fetchall` to read all rows into memory at once. That would be unnecessary if you read rows one by one and wrote them to CSV one by one.

Comment: @deceze but with records of more than 50 million count .Will it be efficient to iterate that many times ?

Comment: You’re iterating some way or another anyway. At least doing it row by row uses hardly any memory and is purely CPU and I/O bound. Give it a try.

Comment: @deceze , let me try that

Comment: You can easily iterate over the cursor to just get one row at a time. That's very efficient because the underlying DB driver will acquire data in chunks and hence use minimal memory. However, it looks like you want the entire 50 million rows in an in-memory dataframe. I think that's where you're likely to have a problem unless you have lots of RAM (virtual or otherwise) available. You should forget about use pandas altogether and write the CSV file yourself (i.e. simple string formatting)

Comment: @DarkKnight , no i don't want that 50 million in one go. That's why i am writing it to the file and discarding the data frame. Also, CSV is just for testing purposes, I will be moving to parquet file format once I solve this record fetching issue.

Comment: @DarkKnight    https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/watson-studio-local/1.2.3?topic=practices-access-large-data  , i tried the method  `ResultIterator` , and my  memory usage jumped like crazy . So i dont think this is going to work.

Comment: @DarkKnight , finally found out that the connector that i was using was giving me buffered  cursor , which was bringing entire result set into memory , now i switched to different library and it is not giving me any issue.

Answer (score 3):

First: rows in Mysql and other RDBMSs *have no inherent order*. So the result set from LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100 is not guaranteed to give the next rows after the result set from LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0. Unless your query includes an ORDER BY clause, the RDBMS gives results in an *unpredictable* order. *Unpredictable* is worse than *random*; with random ordering you have a chance of catching the problem in test. So your current batched approach is incorrect.

Second: Do not ORDER a result set like this except maybe on the primary key.  Your server will take a looooong time to order fifty megarows otherwise. And it will have to do it again for every batch. See you next year! -:)

Third: A very fast way to generate a .csv file is [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html). You should consider doing this, then getting your python program to read the .csv file. You may even be able to find a software tool or script to convert the .csv file to the parquet format.

Fourth: You want to *stream* this result set, not *slurp* it. You want to process it row by row so you don't blow out your python program's RAM. Use a [Raw curso](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorraw.html)r, and use `for (...) in cursor:` to fetch the rows one by one. Process each row before you fetch the next one.

Fifth: Don't worry about the fifty million iterations of your for-loop; your program must read and write that many lines anyhow.

Sixth: if your database is busy as you run this, other users may be blocked. To remediate that blocking execute the SQL statement [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted) right before your SELECT statement.

One of the points of all this RDBMS technology is to allow programs to use data sets that are orders of magnitude larger than available RAM. Streaming the data is the only way to do that when you need to process the entire data set.

Comment: Great list of suggestions . Thanks a lot. One more question , if i do select into outfile , will i be able to save the csv in my local system ? My sql is running at AWS RDS .

Comment: Oh, no, INTO OUTFILE exports its file into the local file system of the  MySQL server. But it's possible the amazonian tribe running their database service have provided a way to write it to an S3 bucket. Look it up or as them for help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how one might efficiently extract the entire contents of a MySQL database table and create a CSV file without the aid of pandas. My table (**ips**) has just 5 columns 3 of which each are declared as VARCHAR(255), one double and one int. The table contains 1 million rows. There are no constraints on the table. This code executes in ~1.75 seconds:-

```
from MySQLdb import _mysql

CSVFILE = '/Users/andy/PrivateStuff/iplist.csv'
TABLE = 'IPS'
CHUNK = 10_000

CONFIG = {
    'user': 'andy',
    'passwd': 'monster',
    'db': 'andy'
}


class Connection():
    def __init__(self, config):
        self._config = config
        self._db = None

    @property
    def db(self):
        if not self._db:
            self._db = _mysql.connection(**self._config)
        return self._db

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        if self._db:
            self._db.close()
            self._db = None


def decode(items):
    return ', '.join([item.decode() if isinstance(item, bytes) else item if item else 'NULL' for item in items])


with open(CSVFILE, 'w') as csvfile:
    with Connection(CONFIG) as conn:
        conn.db.query(f'SHOW COLUMNS FROM {TABLE}')
        r = conn.db.store_result()
        cols = [col[0] for col in r.fetch_row(maxrows=0)]
        print(decode(cols), file=csvfile)
        conn.db.query(f'SELECT * FROM {TABLE}')
        r = conn.db.use_result()
        while (rows := r.fetch_row(maxrows=CHUNK)):
            for row in rows:
                print(decode(row), file=csvfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to dump to Parquet? To use it in a data lake situation? If so, consider using Presto or Spark to connect to MySQL and build a Parquet file for you.

With that said, I have built a Python script to dump a query result to CSV before. If you do it right, you should be able to dump 50 million rows of data into a CSV file in a few minutes (depending on the average size of your rows in bytes).

Pandas is probably slowing you down here. To be honest, I wouldn't even use Python's CSV package. I would just do some basic string manipulation, like this:

```
# create a file to append to
my_file = with open("mytable.csv", "a") as my_file:

    # get sql result
    my_result = my_cursor.fetchall()

    # get amount of columns in result
    row_len = len(my_result[0])

    # iterate over results
    for row in my_result:

        # reset string to append to file
        row_string = ""

        # iterate over all columns except last one
        for col_num in range(row_len - 1):

            # escape double quotes with two double quotes (common CSV pattern)
            escaped_col_val = col.replace("\"", "\"\"")

            # encapsulate the column within double quotes, separate with a comma
            row_string = row_string + "\"{escaped_col_val}\"" + ","

        # same escaping as before, just for last column
        escaped_col_val = col.replace("\"", "\"\"")

        # last column uses a newline instead of comma, to indicate a new row
        row_string = row_string + "\"{escaped_col_val}\"" + "\n"

        # append the result to a string
        my_file.write(row_string)
```

For what it's worth, I am building a new product [SQLPipe](https://sqlpipe.com) that could easily be extended to dump the result of a query to CSV. Perhaps check my profile for contact information.

Comment: are you talking about this ? https://pypi.org/project/sqlpipe/

Comment: Sorry, should have been more explicit. Added a link to the project (sqlpipe.com) in the answer.

Comment: The download option for windows gives access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

> with Limit and offset, but that keeps on getting slowed down with the number of iterations.

Yes, that is a fact.

Instead "remember where you left off"; it will much faster.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Meanwhile, a `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is asking for unpredictable results.  Furthermore, if Inserts and Deletes going such chunking can lead to duplicate and/or missing rows!

If your ultimate goal is to copy it to a CSV file, then simply do

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE "..." ...
```

That will take a single pass -- faster than anything you can possibly do with loops in Python or any other language.

Also consider running this remotely (that is, from your client machine, not the AWS server).

```
mysql -h ... --batch -e "SELECT * FROM tbl" > foo.csv
```

(It may need more parameters.)  (That will produce tabs between columns and an initial line with column names.)

Answer (score 0):

You can order by primary key and query like:

- `select * from table order by id limit 1000` the first time
- and then perform `select * from table where id > %(last_id_you_saw)s order by id limit 1000`

This should not slow down over time.